# Distinct SQL Statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

I'm trying to do a statement to only select distinct records based on the `legacy_call_id__c` field, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I am getting an error,

> Msg 8163, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The text, ntext, or image data
>   type cannot be selected as DISTINCT."

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, CreatedDate, clientId__c, completedDate__c
  , Legacy_Call_ID__c, Description_Short__c
  FROM Customers.dbo.Incident__c
  WHERE Description_Short__c LIKE 'New Hire%'
    OR Description_Short__c LIKE 'Term%'
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2 if that makes a difference.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the schema for `Customers.dbo.Incident__c`?

Comment: Which column(s) are a text, ntext, or image data type?

Comment: the description_short__c is a text column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a column of type `text` or `ntext` in your select query, that is not allowed with `distinct`. Change the column type to `varchar(max)` instead. Or cast it directly in the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Name, 
  CreatedDate, 
  clientId__c, 
  completedDate__c, 
  Legacy_Call_ID__c, 
  CAST(Description_Short__c AS VarChar(max)) --Assuming that is the Text/nText column
FROM Customers.dbo.Incident__c
WHERE Description_Short__c LIKE 'New Hire%'
  OR Description_Short__c LIKE 'Term%'
```

**EDIT**

Not completly sure but something like this might work:

```
 SELECT 
        Name, 
        CreatedDate, 
        clientId__c, 
        completedDate__c, 
        Legacy_Call_ID__c, 
        Description_Short__c
    FROM 
        Customers.dbo.Incident__c As tblOuter
    WHERE
        EXISTS(
            SELECT
                NULL
            FROM 
                Customers.dbo.Incident__c as tblInner
            WHERE 
                (tblInner.Description_Short__c LIKE 'New Hire%' OR
                tblInner.Description_Short__c LIKE 'Term%') AND
                tblInner.Legacy_Call_ID__c = tblOuter.Legacy_Call_ID__c
            GROUP BY
                tblInner.Legacy_Call_ID__c
            HAVING
                MAX(tblInner.CreatedDate) = tblOuter.CreatedDate
            )
```

Comment: I edited it and received the error, Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'max'. I double checked to make sure that it was a text data type

Comment: Are you sure your running SQL server 2008? Test and change the query to varchar(8000) and see if that works.

Comment: I clicked the about link and it said SQL Server 2008 R2.  Altering the varchar ran with no errors, but it still has the duplicate legacy_call_id__c rows appearing.

Comment: If varchar(max) does not work your running SQL server 2000. So you need distinct in column  legacy_call_id__c only, not the other columns in the select? Do you have a Pk column in the table?

Comment: yes, i just need distinct in the legacy call id column.  The other ones I just need the data.  And there is not pk column in the table.

Comment: Ok, i've edited the answer with an alternative solution, not completely sure about it though.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  It looks like it took out some of the dups (the ones with 0). I copied the results over to Excel to verify and it found about 120 more. I don't want to take up anymore of your time, so I'll keep playing around with it.

Answer (score 0):

One of your fields can't be selected because of the format they are in. Try using a

```
CONVERT(nvarchar, Name)
```

in your select statement. IE->

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(nvarchar, Name) as Name, CreatedDate, clientId__c, completedDate__c  , Legacy_Call_ID__c, Description_Short__c
FROM Customers.dbo.Incident__c
WHERE Description_Short__c LIKE 'New Hire%'
OR Description_Short__c LIKE 'Term%'
```

Change nvarchar to whatever field it should be. Play with it and you will get it to go eventually. This solved my select issues, add rep if it solves yours.

Answer (score 0):

See query below. While you're at it, you should look into permanently changing the datatype to varchar(max) instead of text.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, CreatedDate, clientId__c, completedDate__c
  , Legacy_Call_ID__c, convert(varchar(max), Description_Short__c)
  FROM Customers.dbo.Incident__c
  WHERE convert(varchar(max), Description_Short__c) LIKE 'New Hire%'
    OR convert(varchar(max), Description_Short__c) LIKE 'Term%'
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error, Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'max'.

Answer (score 0):

> select distinct records based on the legacy_call_id__c field

Using distinct the way you do will give you the distinct values for all columns combined, not only for `legacy_call_id__c`. You can use the `row_number()` function to get rows with distinct on one field. Here you will get the rows for the highest value of `CreateDate` for each `legacy_call_id__c`.

```
SELECT Name, 
       CreatedDate, 
       clientId__c, 
       completedDate__c, 
       Legacy_Call_ID__c, 
       Description_Short__c
FROM (       
      SELECT Name, 
             CreatedDate, 
             clientId__c, 
             completedDate__c, 
             Legacy_Call_ID__c, 
             Description_Short__c,
             row_number() OVER(
                               PARTITION BY Legacy_Call_ID__c 
                               ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                              ) AS rn
      FROM Customers.dbo.Incident__c
      WHERE Description_Short__c LIKE 'New Hire%'
        OR Description_Short__c LIKE 'Term%'
     ) AS T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```